# Mocking getSession() criteria query

Tags: session, junit, mockito, powermockito

How do I mock getSession() in criteria query.

Currently I am getting null as getSession calls to a method where threadLocal.get() is called which gives null. I have also mocked this threadLocal object.

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. I can tell you are a new user so you may not be familiar with the rules. Usually we provide code and previous attempts to achieve what one is asking for.